# Identifying a stationary point of inflection

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm studying for a Maths A Level in the UK. I understand how to identify *stationary points* but I am less clear about how to then identify if they are *points of inflection*. Having done some research, I think I have identified two possible approaches:

1. **Using the first order derivative**: if you have already identified there is a stationary point at x=0 using the second derivative, return to the first derivative and plug x = 0.1 and x = -0.1 (or similar values either side of 0) into the equation. The resulting answers will have the **same** sign if x=0 is a point of inflection.
2. **Using the second order derivative**: if there is a stationary point at x=0, plug x = 0.1 and x = -0.1 (or similar values either side of 0) into the equation. The resulting answers should have **different** signs if x=0 is a point of inflection

**Is that right?** And if so, do these approaches always work? Many of the explanations I've found online only use the first derivative approach. However, the main textbook I've been using says the second derivative should be used (but the method is poorly explained, hence my confusion). Grateful for anyone that can clarify